# Kotlin(Android Studio) - I Dont wanna go to the new activity if TextFields are empty

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-room

I am practicing 'kotlin room persistence' library saving data and showing to the another activity by pressing save user button, but i don't wanna go to the new activity if the fields are empty.

i have tried simple if statement

```
if (user.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()) {
   Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() 
}
```

this one.. but it's not working either..

here's my Code:

```
package com.example.app

import android.arch.persistence.room.Room
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.widget.Toast
import com.example.app.roomDataBase.AppDb
import com.example.app.roomDataBase.UserDataClassRoom
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.create_user.*

class CreateUser : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.create_user)

        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
            applicationContext
            , AppDb::class.java, "database-name"
        ).allowMainThreadQueries()
            .build()

        btnSaveUser.setOnClickListener {

            val user = UserDataClassRoom(
                first_Name.text.toString().trim(),
                Last_Name.text.toString(),
                email.text.toString()
            )

            /* if (user.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                } */
            db.userDao().insertAll(user)


            val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put return statement after Toast.

Comment: but i am still curious why it is used `if (user.toString().trim().isNotEmpty())` instead of `trim().isEmpty`

Comment: You have not added the else statement. Either you add else statement and specify what you want to do, or put return statement.

Comment: when i entered some data in **textfields** its is still saying fields are empty and i tried it with else statement as well

Comment: Post your updated code.

Comment: even with **.isEmpty()**
            `if (user.toString().trim().isNotEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                //return@setOnClickListener

            }else {
                db.userDao().insertAll(user)
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }`

Answer (score 0):

Your if-statement is wrong, it checks if the value is not empty instead of being empty, you need to change **isNotEmpty()** to **isEmpty()** as:

```
    if (user.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        // return No need if you specify else
    }
   else{
       db.userDao().insertAll(user)
       val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
       startActivity(intent)
   }
```

Comment: It's not working, it is still making the **textViews** with empty fields, now my code is: `if (user.toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
               // return@setOnClickListener

            } else {
                db.userDao().insertAll(user)
                val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
            }`

Comment: This means that the **user.toString()**  is a wrong value to check and its always not empty, I don't know if you did override the **toString()** in the User.java or not. if you did not override it then its the time to do it, Or you can check on each value separetly as :
if(firstName.isEmpty() || lastName.isEmpty() || ..){ toast...} else {.. code here}